# Como eliminar el ultimo elemento de un ciclo for loop en C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

> Hola quisiera saber como eliminar o evitar el ultimo ciclo de un for,
> ya que cuando se ejecuta el for añado comas para detallar la
> separacion de elementos y al realizar el ciclo se al final se agrega
> la coma.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {

int size_vector = 0;
// Declaring a size vector
cout << "Size of the vector: "; cin >> size_vector;
// Printing a vector size warning.
cout << "Your vector need to have " << size_vector << " elements" <<endl;

vector <int> vector_container (size_vector); //Declaring the vector container
cout << "Insert values : ";
for(int iterator = 0; iterator < size_vector; iterator++) {
    cin >> vector_container.at(iterator); //Iterating the input by stored in vector
}
cout << "Vector elements: ";
for(int iterator = 0; iterator < size_vector; iterator++) {
    cout << vector_container.at(iterator) << ", "; //Iterating vector's elements.
}

}
```

Ejemplo de consola:

```
Size of the vector: 3
Your vector need to have 3 elements
Insert values : 1 2 3
Vector elements: 1, 2, 3,
```

**DEL RESULTADO "VECTOR ELEMENTS: " QUISIERA ELIMINAR LA ULTIMA COMA.**

Answer (score 2):

No te hace falta evitar la última vuelta de un bucle; de hecho, ni siquiera te hace falta bucle. Usa [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) de la cabecera `<numeric>`:

```
std::vector<int> numeros { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

std::cout << 
std::accumulate(++numeros.begin(), numeros.end(), std::to_string(*numeros.begin()),
    [](std::string &s, int n)
    {
        return s + ',' + std::to_string(n);
    });
```

El código anterior produce [la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##XY7JasQwEETP1lcUBDJ23BmyL2PjHwkhKLIwArs1aMll8Lc78hIyzKWhql9Xlzoeb1UvuZumK8Oqj61GbawPTsuhEf9ecgx3586PVsG6c4fjoJ1RjRCGAwZpOC/ESWQ@tIfDitdp02ABrccJ94QHwiPhifBMeCG8Et4I7xgrsV0qGwPqGpuUSsUh9jLovCy3pP237uZv9Be919zOcrkI9mutn99c8In4@MwXaCVw7Qlzey5ElqpnTofoGB4ldrRL8yKRi0pkYzGX3dC7SozT9As):

> ```
> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
> ```

Puedes generalizar el proceso con una plantilla para usar cualquier tipo de contenedor y separador:

```
template <typename contenedor_t>
std::string join(const contenedor_t &contenedor, const std::string &separador)
{
    auto begin = std::begin(contenedor);
    auto next = std::next(begin);
    auto end = std::end(contenedor);

    return std::accumulate(next, end, std::to_string(*begin), [&separador](std::string &s, auto n)
    {
        return s + separador + std::to_string(n);
    });
}

int main()
{
    int numeros[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::cout << join(numeros, ", ");

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHtasMwDPxdP4XYoKSbBvv@6Lq@SCnFdUTxaOTgyGOj9NkzO26bBIKR7k5nXWzq@s7sNe/a9tqy2YeSYGFdI550tVQ9FhHLuyHyQ0acHyIcKvLWLJUSquq9lojJX02sKwLjWIipdH4jS9VIOZ9nT/h2lotINzISwbTvEDI/HJs2VGuvIztTBzXRQRxsaWcZvrKua4reZPZ5UjH9ylmU6qJTXmji8szGcmygJp4keM60NiZUIQUtkg@mUcyUuE3es7jJ7girfuN1MU6CkBebqUmMcrkDbuEykuqxcbfxMR5HpSwLVDrG7f5F6rrHcM1qDQd4QHhEeEJ4RnhBeEV4Q3hH@IBjitT5GhcEFov8GqdhhKv4DWPfx9va9h8)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así:

```
for(int iterator = 0; iterator < size_vector; iterator++) {
    cout << vector_container.at(iterator);

    if(iterator < size_vector - 1) {
        cout << ", ";
    }
}
```

Si sólo quieres quitar la "," lo más sencillo es hacerlo usando el contador del "for".

Answer (score 1):

Una forma fácil podría ser que la coma sólo aparezca mientras el iterador esté una unidad por debajo del tamaño del vector. Es decir, sustiuir esto:

```
for(int iterator = 0; iterator < size_vector; iterator++) {
    cout << vector_container.at(iterator) << ", "; //Iterating vector's elements.
```

Por esto:

```
 for(int iterator = 0; iterator < size_vector; iterator++)
    {
        cout << vector_container.at(iterator);
        if (iterator<size_vector-1)
        {
         cout<< ", "; //Iterating vector's elements.
        }
    }
```

Por otro lado sólo dos apuntes:
No uses la palabra `iterator`, ya que es un objeto que se usa para recorrer colecciones. Mejor `iterador`u otra palabra no reservada.

Por otro lado, toda función principal ha de tener un retorno. `int main()` ha de acabar con un `return 0;`

Usando el iterador de forma correcta, el resultado podría ser así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int size_vector = 0;
// Declaring a size vector
    cout << "Size of the vector: ";
    cin >> size_vector;
// Printing a vector size warning.
    cout << "Your vector need to have " << size_vector << " elements" <<endl;

    vector <int> vector_container (size_vector); //Declaring the vector container
    cout << "Insert values : ";
    for(auto iterator = vector_container.begin(); iterator < vector_container.end(); iterator++)
    {
        cin >> *iterator; //Iterating the input by stored in vector
    }
    cout << "Vector elements: ";
    for(auto iterator = vector_container.begin(); iterator < vector_container.end(); iterator++)
    {
        cout << *iterator;
        if (iterator < vector_container.end()-1)
        {
         cout<< ", "; //Iterating vector's elements.
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```